# How can i get next-auth session in nextjs 12 middlware

Tags: next.js

I was experimenting with the new nextjs features and while using next-auth inside the pages/_middleware.ts this doesn't seem to work

```
import { getSession } from 'next-auth/client';
import type { NextFetchEvent, NextRequest } from 'next/server'
import {NextResponse} from 'next/server'
async function middleware(req: NextRequest, ev: NextFetchEvent) {
    let session = await getSession({ req });

      return new Response('Auth required', {
        status: 401,
        headers: {
          'WWW-Authenticate': 'Basic realm="Secure Area"',
        },
      })
}
export {middleware}
```

this works in api routes but the "req" object is NextApiRequest unlike here. so how can i get the user object inside the middleware so i can do a role/authentication check.

Comment: Can't you cast `req` to `NextApiRequest` type? Are you getting any errors?

Comment: I tried that and getSession returns null

Comment: full log- `eval` not allowed in Middleware pages/admin/_middleware
null
warn  - ./node_modules/react/cjs/react.development.js
`eval` not allowed in Middleware pages/admin/_middleware

Comment: If something's internally calling `eval()` then that means you can't use `getSession` in the middleware. See https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/edge-runtime#unsupported-apis.

Comment: vs code also highligts this as an error when i try and use NextRequest- Type 'NextRequest' is missing the following properties from type 'NextApiRequest': query, env, aborted, httpVersion, and 48 more.

Answer (score 7):

What worked for me was to use the helper function `getToken()` and decrypt the session information from the token which will be sent along with the request, i.e *req* parameter

Here is a sample of my _middleware.ts

```
export async function middleware(
  req: NextApiRequest,
  ev: NextFetchEvent
) {
  const token = await getToken({
    req,
    secret: process.env.SECRET,
  });
  console.log("from middleware ", token);
  return NextResponse.next();
}
```

Note *process.env.SECRET* refers to the secret you used in your `[...nextauth].ts` configuration for *jwt*

Comment: While using req: NextRquest, Typescript gives an error: Type 'NextRequest' is missing the following properties from type 'NextApiRequest': query, env, aborted, httpVersion, and 46 more.ts(2740)
jwt.d.ts(47, 3): The expected type comes from property 'req' which is declared here on type 'GetTokenParams<false>'

Comment: I've edited the answer, req should be typed as NextApiRequest